# 85% of the population is/are

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. 85% of the population of the USA **is** Christian.
> 2. 85% of the population of the USA **are** Christian.

Which one is correct?

Comment: "Population" is a singular noun, so one would expect singular agreement. But it's also a collective noun, so singular agreement can be overridden, i.e.  you can use either singular "is" or plural "are".

Answer (score 3):

As user BillJ says in [a comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234855/85-of-the-population-is-are#comment445688_234855), singular nouns normally require singular agreement in that construction with *percent* (BrE *per cent*), while collective nouns which would normally be followed by a verb in the singular could also take a plural verb. A plural noun would, similar to the first case, require a plural verb.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL) by Huddleston et al., 2002, gives these examples on page 504:

> 1. One percent of students<sub>PLURAL</sub> <strike>takes</strike> / take drugs.
> 2. One percent of the electorate<sub>NORMALLY SINGULAR</sub> takes / take drugs.
> 3. One percent of the cheese<sub>SINGULAR</sub> was / <strike>were</strike> contaminated.

*Population*, like the *electorate* above, is a **collective noun** which normally takes a singular verb, with a possible plural override, so the sentence in question would be grammatical with either *is* or *are*:

> 85% of the population of the USA **is** / **are** Christian.

---

This works because *percent* is a so-called **number-transparent** noun, like *lot* in *a lot of students take drugs* and *a lot of the cheese was contaminated*, so the number of the **oblique** (*students*, *the electorate*, *the cheese* in the sentences above) is allowed to "percolate" up to determine the number of the entire noun phrase (such as *a lot of students* (plural) or *one percent of the cheese* (singular)).

For more information see pp.349–50; 501–504 in CGEL.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm picturing one percent of a particular elector taking drugs.